# How to disable power_efficient kernel's feature?

Tags: linux-kernel, arch-linux

The question, in fact, has been asked in the subject.

I use the ArchLinux. I tried to put the `workqueue.power_efficient=false` to the grub.cfg, but after reboot the contents of the `/sys/modules/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient` is 'Y'.

Comment: Did you remember to run the `update-grub` command afterwards?

Comment: @JannePikkarainen, yes, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set the parameter in grub would be:

```sh
workqueue.power_efficient=0
```

Then update grub via the `grub-mkconfig` tool after making changes to `/etc/default/grub`:

```sh
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```